# escaped string is not recognized

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am building a web-scraping application using python, requests and BeautifulSoup.

I declared a class variable as:

```
class myClass(object):
    TAG = "\"span\",{\"data-automation\":\"jobListingDate\"}"
```

I verified this TAG by using `print self.TAG`

and I got the output from `print self.TAG` is `"span",{"data-automation":"jobListingDate"}` which suggests `self.TAG` is the same as this string `"span",{"data-automation":"jobListingDate"}`

But the following two lines of code produced completed different results:

- `r = requests.get("someURL")`
- `html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")`
- `html.find(self.TAG) #this line does not find anything at all`
- `html.find("span",{"data-automation":"jobListingDate"}) #this line does find what I am after`

I am confused, how `self.TAG` is not the same as this string `"span",{"data-automation":"jobListingDate"}`, have I not escaped anything properly?

Comment: What is `self`? What is `html.find`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, problem solved. Thank you for your comment still, I should have clarified them from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `html.find(self.TAG)` you're actually only putting a single string as a parameter, namely:

```
html.find('"span",{"data-automation":"jobListingDate"}')
```

Notice the single quote `'` around the string, which is the same as `"\"span\",{\"data-automation\":\"jobListingDate\"}"`

in your second example `html.find("span",{"data-automation":"jobListingDate"})` we're talking about two parameters.

Of course this will behave differently.

Comment: thank you, I used type() to see if html and self.TAG were of the same type, then I noticed something wrong, exactly as you said.